# Comparing two matrices column-wise in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, function, matlab, sorting, matrix

I have two matrices in Matlab both are almost similar except that the columns of both the matrices appear at different column number.

For example,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIICW.jpg)
I need to find that each column of x appears at which column number of A.
Any help or idea is highly appreciated.

ismember function only finds if the columns are present in the other matrix or not.

Comment: Did you look at the 2nd output of ismember? That returns the index of where it found the match.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. i have managed to find a solution to my problem. i tried ismember with other options too but the result wasn't what I was looking for. Anyway, I ll keep that in mind if I have another similar problem.

Comment: @KanwalChaudhary Perhaps you'll share your solution as an answer below for the benefit of future visitors. Also, please do not post images of data (or code). Use plain text instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume with your example that your matrices (say A and B, dimensions n x  p) are boolean (you don't say it in your question).

In this case, here is a simple trick : compute the p x p matrix M=A^TB (transpose of A times B) and look for the entries equal to n... Writing P=(M>=n), you get a permutation matrix (one 1 per row and per column ; all the other entries being equal to 0). Then apply this matrix P to the column vector (1,2,.... p) to obtain the permutation array.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. i have managed to find a solution to my problem. I tried to upload the image of my sample matrices A and B but the image doesnt display with the text. However, your technique seems interesting. I will try that too.